# Clojure: Apply a nested vector format to a flattened vector

Tags: vector, clojure, nested, structure, flatten

For example, I have the following nested vector:

```
[[[0.582198689235419 -0.34713183143727 0.4685311493624731]
  [-0.38928013774079284 -0.5901700383677557 -0.37573234072157]
  [0.6716356761877877 -0.19645167952721243 -0.5700686091940252]]
 [[0.0027162308840597005 -0.4483592764429284 -0.4766278022217257 -0.2724018313051576]
  [-0.2765881229144672 -0.8030656496255356 -0.16159395457031567 -0.27432324260043084]
  [-0.6154630466545907 -0.60573539482247 0.4417814561800192 -0.5559788990464504]
  [0.6194560094536031 -0.3663074359460578 -0.5704311251195602 0.7194827876969362]]]
```

And I have the following flattened vector:

```
(0.5366343712173423
 -0.816449781850872
 -0.16066485785704843
 0.9816561233924161
 -0.09646744313584676
 -0.2619662625757997
 -0.9946004265996822
 -0.14096299956754854
 0.579260850612288
 -0.827601452607939
 -0.24934665032374648
 -0.42272393175707873
 0.11239245249400165
 -0.29878238708035043
 -0.61522274672097
 0.8298721730401472
 0.5016214138116059
 0.11633537727916243
 -0.0631891708267196
 -0.26569217599364303
 0.20900664784109668
 0.2005869506108401
 -0.2658279978034501
 0.3383997403318165
 -0.09353513546647907)
```

I want the flattened vector to be converted to a nested vector that follows the same structure as the nested vector presented above. Is there a core function in Clojure or a library that does this? I have some ideas of how to solve this problem, but all of them seem very very inefficient, and this operation will be used with big vectors.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a fun question to answer, because it is one of the very few times when I think using a zipper makes things easier instead of harder. The idea is to just make a vector-zip of the nested vector, to represent the desired structure, and call zip/next on it repeatedly; whenever we get to a node which is a leaf, we replace its value with the next one from the input sequence.

Note that this assumes there are exactly as many items in the nested structure as in the flattened list; if that is not the case, you will probably get an error of some kind, who knows.

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn replace-values [structure values]
  (loop [z (z/vector-zip structure)
         values (seq values)]
    (cond (not values) (z/root z)
          (z/branch? z) (recur (z/next z) values)
          :else (recur (-> z
                           (z/replace (first values))
                           (z/next))
                       (next values)))))

user> (replace-values '[[[0.582198689235419 -0.34713183143727 0.4685311493624731]
                         [-0.38928013774079284 -0.5901700383677557 -0.37573234072157]
                         [0.6716356761877877 -0.19645167952721243 -0.5700686091940252]]
                        [[0.0027162308840597005 -0.4483592764429284 -0.4766278022217257 -0.2724018313051576]
                         [-0.2765881229144672 -0.8030656496255356 -0.16159395457031567 -0.27432324260043084]
                         [-0.6154630466545907 -0.60573539482247 0.4417814561800192 -0.5559788990464504]
                         [0.6194560094536031 -0.3663074359460578 -0.5704311251195602 0.7194827876969362]]]
                      '(0.5366343712173423
                        -0.816449781850872
                        -0.16066485785704843
                        0.9816561233924161
                        -0.09646744313584676
                        -0.2619662625757997
                        -0.9946004265996822
                        -0.14096299956754854
                        0.579260850612288
                        -0.827601452607939
                        -0.24934665032374648
                        -0.42272393175707873
                        0.11239245249400165
                        -0.29878238708035043
                        -0.61522274672097
                        0.8298721730401472
                        0.5016214138116059
                        0.11633537727916243
                        -0.0631891708267196
                        -0.26569217599364303
                        0.20900664784109668
                        0.2005869506108401
                        -0.2658279978034501
                        0.3383997403318165
                        -0.09353513546647907))

[[[0.5366343712173423 -0.816449781850872 -0.16066485785704843]
  [0.9816561233924161 -0.09646744313584676 -0.2619662625757997]
  [-0.9946004265996822 -0.14096299956754854 0.579260850612288]]
 [[-0.827601452607939 -0.24934665032374648 -0.42272393175707873 0.11239245249400165]
  [-0.29878238708035043 -0.61522274672097 0.8298721730401472 0.5016214138116059]
  [0.11633537727916243 -0.0631891708267196 -0.26569217599364303 0.20900664784109668]
  [0.2005869506108401 -0.2658279978034501 0.3383997403318165 -0.09353513546647907]]]
```